# Breakpoint leaves blank space in content

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, breakpoints

At my breakpoint of 1100px I have told CSS to remove a div which holds an image. However, the rest of the content does not move across and there is a large blank area (as if the div is still there). All I would like to happen is for the content to all shift over and fill the page. This error on occurs on this singular page and this specific to this very break point.

```css
  /*minimised browser winddow */

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter form,
  aside#sidebar {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  aside {
    display: none;
  }
  #newsletter h1 {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* 768 tablet */

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #imagery {
    display: none;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 275%;
  }
  #showcase p {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #newsletter button,
  .quote button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #newsletter form input[type="email"],
  .quote input,
  .quote textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .col-25,
  .col-75 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  /* nav */
  ul.topnav li {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    /*  'un' float the list items so they return to displaying vertically */
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* 400 pixels mobile phone */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100%
  }
  header ul {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3a2264e344.js"></script>
<script src="html9shiv.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="wrench.png" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="desciption" content="Darran Brady Plumbing">
<meta name="keywords" content="Plumbing, Boilers, Showers, Central Heating, Kitchens, Bathrooms, Installations, Landlord Services, Horsham, West Sussex, Sussex,Barns Green, Billingshurst,Broadbridge Heath,Christ's Hospital, Clemsfold, Copsale,Colgate,Cowfold, Faygate, Handcross, Horsham, Itchingfield, Kingsfold,Lambs Farm,Lower Beeding,Mannings Heath, Maplehurst, Monks Gate, Nuthurst, Partridge Green, Pease Pottage, Roffey, Rowhook, Rusper, Rudgwick, Southwater, Slinfold, Warnham ">
<meta name="author" content="DB, Darran, Brady, Darran Brady">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1><span class="highlight">DB</span> Plumbing</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <li class="active"><a href="home9.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about9.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="services9.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="coverage9.html">Coverage</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact9.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:140%;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="dark">
      <div class="callus"><a href="tel:+07756848657"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" ></i></a></div>
      <h2>Our Story</h2>
    </div>
  </div>





  <section id="main">
    <div class="container">

      <article id="main-col">
        <p>
          Our customer's individual requirements are important to us at DB Plumbing. We always provide quality service and products and combined with honesty has made us the first choice of many homes in the Horsham area.</p>

        <div class="dark">

          <h3>What We Offer</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Plumbing and Heating Services</li>
            <li>Gas Safe Registered: 202542</li>
            <li>VAT Registered</li>
            <li>25 years of expertise</li>
            <li>Plumbing and Heating Services</li>
            <li>Heating Engineer Qualified</li>
            <li>VAT Registered</li>
            <li>100% Satisfaction Garauntee</li>
          </ul>
      </article>

      <aside id="sidebar">
        <div class="dark">
          <h3>Satisfaction Garauntee</h3>
          <p>Reputation matters. 98% of our customer would reccomend us to a friend.</p>
          <a href="http://www.checkatrade.com/DBPlumbing/Reviews.aspx"><img class="catsmall" src="cat.png" alt="checkatradelogo"></a>
        </div>
      </aside>
      </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div>
      <p>Darren Brady Plumbing Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
      <p>Registered in England No. 4364232</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: I can't see any black space. I can see that, image is removed and replaced by footer.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh here's a link to the page.http://bsch-dev.chi.ac.uk/~ZCOMBER1/Version%209/about9.html

Comment: @DhavalJardosh and minimise the screen width to 1200px, roughly half the desktop size. Thanks

Comment: ok, so you want your, left div(block) to come in the center. right?

Comment: please provide your complete css. Fork this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/bYKbXj?editors=1100), place all your css, save and send back to me. Thanks

Comment: @DhavalJardosh both divs to extend across the page like the top one, yes

Comment: @DhavalJardosh https://codepen.io/c9mber/pen/vWrYEJ

Comment: @DhavalJardosh any luck?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want something like [this](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/bYKbXj?editors=1100). Try to resize the width of the window.

Comment: Or you want something like this? [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/WXyNzq)

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Perfect, thanks. What was missing?

Comment: Please check the answer @simeonejacx

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting your container class with a width:100% in your @media css will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in 2 ways to center the div(in your case "What we offer" block)

**Center block by `position:relative`**

```
#main-col{
    position:relative;
    left:15%;    //This can differ, and you can keep whatever you see it's best
}
```

**Increase the `min-width` of that particular block**

```
#main-col{
    min-width: 100%;   //Remember, you need to force the width, 
                       //so width:100% won't work here. Hence min-width
}
```

---

```css
  body {
  font: 100%/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Style the list 'container'  */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Float the list items left - this is the 'magic' that turns a vertical list into a horizontal row */

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}


/* style the links  */

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 100%;
}


/* hover */

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  color: gold;
}


/* Hide the icon initially  */

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Global */

.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Allows the burger nav and branding to sit on the same line */
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 50px;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.subscribe {
  height: 38px;
  background: gold;
  border: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.dark {
  padding: 25px;
  background: #35424a;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.maps {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.maps iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}


/* Header **/

header {
  background: #35424a;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: gold 5px solid;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 100%;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight {
  color: gold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: gold;
}

h3 .bronze {
  color: #cc6633;
}

h3 .silver {
  color: silver;
}

h3 .gold {
  color: gold;
}

img.catsmall {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Showcase */

#showcase {
  min-height: 350px;
}

#showcase h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 500%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 120%;
}


/* Newsletter */

#newsletter {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #35424a
}

#newsletter h1 {
  float: left;
}

#newsletter form {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"] {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 250px;
}


/* Sidebar */

aside#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

section#contactus .quote input,
section#contactus .quote textarea {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Main-col */

article#main-col {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}


/* Imagery */

#imagery {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#imagery .box {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#imagery .box i {
  font-size: 800%;
}


/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container .visuals {
  float: right;
}

.container .callus {
  float: right
}

.fa-phone {
  color: gold;
}


/* Services */

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: vertical;
}


/* Floating column for labels: 25% width */

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Floating column for inputs: 75% width */

.col-75 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

footer {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: black;
  background-color: gold;
  text-align: center;
}


/*minimised browser winddow */

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter form,
  aside#sidebar {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  aside {
    display: none;
  }
  #newsletter h1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #main-col {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}


/* 768 tablet */

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #imagery {
    display: none;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 275%;
  }
  #showcase p {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #newsletter button,
  .quote button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #newsletter form input[type="email"],
  .quote input,
  .quote textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .col-25,
  .col-75 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  /* nav */
  ul.topnav li {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    /*  'un' float the list items so they return to displaying vertically */
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* 400 pixels mobile phone */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100%
  }
  header ul {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  /* CSS reset */
  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers article,
  aside,
  details,
  figcaption,
  figure,
  footer,
  header,
  hgroup,
  menu,
  nav,
  section {
    display: block;
  }
  body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: contain;
  }
  ol,
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  blockquote,
  q {
    quotes: none;
  }
  blockquote:before,
  blockquote:after,
  q:before,
  q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
  }
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3a2264e344.js"></script>
<script src="html9shiv.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="wrench.png" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="desciption" content="Darran Brady Plumbing">
<meta name="keywords" content="Plumbing, Boilers, Showers, Central Heating, Kitchens, Bathrooms, Installations, Landlord Services, Horsham, West Sussex, Sussex,Barns Green, Billingshurst,Broadbridge Heath,Christ's Hospital, Clemsfold, Copsale,Colgate,Cowfold, Faygate, Handcross, Horsham, Itchingfield, Kingsfold,Lambs Farm,Lower Beeding,Mannings Heath, Maplehurst, Monks Gate, Nuthurst, Partridge Green, Pease Pottage, Roffey, Rowhook, Rusper, Rudgwick, Southwater, Slinfold, Warnham ">
<meta name="author" content="DB, Darran, Brady, Darran Brady">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1><span class="highlight">DB</span> Plumbing</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <li class="active"><a href="home9.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about9.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="services9.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="coverage9.html">Coverage</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact9.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:140%;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="dark">
      <div class="callus"><a href="tel:+07756848657"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" ></i></a></div>
      <h2>Our Story</h2>
    </div>
  </div>





  <section id="main">
    <div class="container">

      <article id="main-col">
        <p>
          Our customer's individual requirements are important to us at DB Plumbing. We always provide quality service and products and combined with honesty has made us the first choice of many homes in the Horsham area.</p>

        <div class="dark">

          <h3>What We Offer</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Plumbing and Heating Services</li>
            <li>Gas Safe Registered: 202542</li>
            <li>VAT Registered</li>
            <li>25 years of expertise</li>
            <li>Plumbing and Heating Services</li>
            <li>Heating Engineer Qualified</li>
            <li>VAT Registered</li>
            <li>100% Satisfaction Garauntee</li>
          </ul>

      </article>

      <aside id="sidebar">
        <div class="dark">
          <h3>Satisfaction Garauntee</h3>
          <p>Reputation matters. 98% of our customer would reccomend us to a friend.</p>
          <a href="http://www.checkatrade.com/DBPlumbing/Reviews.aspx"><img class="catsmall" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d5/7a/e1/d57ae1e0abaa478e79388007b6d6dd09--woman-face-woman-style.jpg" alt="checkatradelogo"></a>
        </div>
      </aside>
      </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div>
      <p>Darren Brady Plumbing Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
      <p>Registered in England No. 4364232</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```